# Searching for Directed acyclic graph data

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, programming, computing

I need some DAG graph for my research. The representation of the graphs is needed to be in edge-list representation.

Comment: I don't know if anyone actually keeps lists of DAGs per se, but you could take an existing dataset and create DAGs from it? Perhaps the wikipedia category list?

Comment: Why don't you download any river network  and extracted the edge list yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good places to look for graph and network datasets

- Awesome list by [briatte/awesome-network-analysis](https://github.com/briatte/awesome-network-analysis#datasets)
- [Stanford Large Network Dataset Collection](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/index.html)
- [UCI Network Data Repository](https://networkdata.ics.uci.edu/resources.php)
- [ASU Network Datasets](http://socialcomputing.asu.edu/pages/datasets)
- [Aminer Datasets for Social Network Analysis](https://aminer.org/data-sna)
- [Network Repository](http://networkrepository.com/)
- [Datasets](http://networksciencebook.com/translations/en/resources/data.html) from the book "Network Science" by Albert-László Barabási
- [UCINET format datasets](https://sites.google.com/site/ucinetsoftware/datasets)

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a satisfactory result though I searched a lot. So I have created my own dataset. You can go to this link https://github.com/S-Nakib/Randomly-genrated-Directed-Acyclic-Graph-with-fixed-nodes.-
I have posted it here so that if someone later comes here searching it again.